# Workflow 2013 keeps updating the items on behalf of the users, even if the condition does not match

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, workflow-manager, workflow2013

I am working on a sharepoint online classic team site, and i added a custom list which contain a field named "Responsibility ID" which is of type "Single line of text", and i set it as hidden inside the New/Edit forms using this PnP script:-

```
$fieldTitle = "ResponsibilityID"
$customfield = $Context.Site.RootWeb.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle($fieldTitle) 
$customfield.SetShowInEditForm($true)
$customfield.SetShowInDisplayForm($true)
$customfield.UpdateAndPushChanges($true)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

then i define the below workflow 2013 to get executed when item is added/updated, and i chose to update the "Responsiblity ID" to be equal to `RES[ItemID]`:-
[image]

but the problem in my case is that whenever i update the item , the workflow will cause the item to be updated, as follow:-
[image]

so not sure why the IF statement inside my above workflow is being ignored? so even if the "Responsiblity ID" equals `RES[ItemID]`, the workflow will update the item.

Comment: remove the empty condition and then check if the condition works? i believe, responID never empty...

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP Thanks fro the reply.. i already did that but did not work for me.. could the reason be that the custom column "Responsibility ID" is hidden inside the new/edit forms.. but this should not cause the issue... not sure what is going on!!

Comment: I am seeing it differently....what is type of current value column? I think one is integer and other is string

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP the "Responsibility ID" custom column is of type single line of text.. now i find this interesting thing.. i uncheck the "Automatically update the workflow status to the current stage name" inside the Settings section for the workflow inside SP designer, and now my problem is fixed!! seems previously the workflow was modifying the item by updating the workflow status to the current stage name..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a test in SharePoint online, i create a SharePoint 2013 platform workflow like the following and choose "Automatically update the workflow status to the current stage name".

[image]

I create an alert on the list which send me alert with all changes.

After i run the workflow, both the version and modified are changed, i receive an email alert which indicates the Stage1 has been changed.

[image]

So the problem is that if we choose "Automatically update the workflow status to the current stage name", it will change the Stage1 which results to the items be changed,then the version and modified are changed.

Comment: thanks for the reply ..so do you think there will be any problem/issue if we uncheck the "Automatically update the workflow status to the current stage name""?

Comment: There is no problem to uncheck the "Automatically update the workflow status to the current stage name".